# Подсчитать размер табицы SQLite

Tags: sqlite3, sqlite

Существует ли возможность подсчитать, сколько байт занимает конкретная таблица базы данных в `SQLite3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделать дамп, посмотреть размер